# Detect textbox change after async callback from C#

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, events, client-server

There are many solutions for this, but I think that this is little different.

The field "Estado" (State) at the right, is automatically completed after clicking a grill row. I want to hide/show icons depending that field.

I have tried with the onChange atribbute, but doesnt work, it have to be written "manually"
I also tried with some jquery functions from this page, but its not detecting the event
Finally, I have tried to change the visibility of the icons from the cs file, but its not synchronous, the client is not getting the event.

What else can I do?

Thank you very much

[(1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oglxm.jpg)

[(2)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZGXfy.jpg)

Fusion is just a framework, the same as a textbox with more functions

```
<Fusion:CampoTexto   runat="server" onChange="alerta();"  ID="campoEstadoTarjeta" Requerido="false" Width="200" CssClass="Campo" 


<script>
    function alerta(){
       alert("asd"
    }
</script
```

This wont work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
           $('#campoEstadoTarjeta').change(function () { alert('test'); });
       });
```

Comment: Edited @SimonPrice

Answer (score 0):

try something like this and this should work for you

```
<Fusion:CampoTexto runat="server" ID="campoEstadoTarjeta" Requerido="false" Width="200" CssClass="Campo" 

$("#campoEstadoTarjeta'").keyup(function(){
    alert("this works");
});
```

so each time you key press is completed then the event will fire and you should then be able to do what you want to do.

if youre looking for another textbox to have that value then you would do something like this

```
 $("#campoEstadoTarjeta'").keyup(function(){
    $("#myOtherTextBox").val($("#campoEstadoTarjeta'").val());
 });
```

Answer (score -1):

JavaScript listeners will be lost after an Async PostBack in the Control is located inside the UpdatePanel. You need to re-register your TextBox.

Wrap your listener binding in a function.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    bindFunction();

    function bindFunction() {
        $("#<%= campoEstadoTarjeta.ClientID %>").keyup(function () {
            alert('test')
        });
    }
</script>
```

Then call that function after Async PostBack.

```
protected void ButtonInsideUpdatePanel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "bindFunction", "bindFunction();", true);
}
```